# How many solutions are there to the equation?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I need to find the number of solutions in positive integers to the following equation:

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 19$$

where $x_2 \neq 2x_3$ and $x_1 \neq x_2$

I know to solve the cases like $x_1 \ge 2x_3$, but I don't understand how to do the jump from this inequality to the case where they're not equal.

Any hint or guide would be much appreciated!

Comment: Assuming you want solutions in positive integers? In $\mathbb{R}$ solutions are infinite.

Comment: @vvg yes indeed, I'll edit the post (:

Comment: For a start, put $x_2 = 2x_3 + X_3$ and $x_2 = x_1 + X_2$ where $X_2, X_3$ are integers. This takes care of inequality criteria. You then get a Bezout type equation in 4 variables.

Comment: Then use Extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @vvg we never used this algorithm in class, but I'll try look into it

Comment: Ok, then use this. The smallest value for $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ is 1. Therefore, each one goes from $1 \cdots 19$. Now eliminate the values in $x_2 = x_3$ and $x_1 = x_2$.

Comment: Hint: $x_1$ has 19 possibilities. $x_2$ has one less possibility compared to $x_1$ due to $x_1 \ne x_2$. From the set of 18 values for $x_2$, if you remove the even numbers, you should have $9$ possibilities for $x_3$. and x_4 has ?? possibilities. Therefore, there are ?? choices?

Comment: @vvg eventually what I did is using the inclusion-exclusion principle in the following way: (sum of all possible solutions for the equation) - (sum of the solutions where $x_1= x_2$) - (sum of the solutions where $x_2= 2x_3$) - (sum of the solutions where $x_1= x_2$ and $x_2= 2x_3$)

Answer (score 3):

A generating function approach. We start with the number of solutions of
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=19}\tag{1}\\
&\color{blue}{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\geq 1}
\end{align*}
We represent the solutions of a variable $x_j\geq 1, 1\leq j\leq 4$ as generating function for $x_j$ which is
\begin{align*}
z+z^2+z^3+\cdots=\frac{z}{1-z}
\end{align*}
Using the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series, the number of solutions of (1) is
\begin{align*}
[z^{19}]\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^4&=[z^{15}]\frac{1}{(1-z)^4}=\binom{-4}{15}(-1)^{15}\color{blue}{=816}
\end{align*}

**Condition $x_2\ne 2x_3$:**

- We respect this condition by subtracting from (1) all solutions with $\color{blue}{x_2=2x_3}$. This gives
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{x_1+3x_3+x_4=19}\tag{2}
  \end{align*}
  A generating function for $3x_3$ is
  $z^3+z^6+\cdots=\frac{z^3}{1-z^3}$
  The number of positive solutions of (2) is
  \begin{align*}
  [z^{19}]\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^2\left(\frac{z^3}{1-z^3}\right)=[z^{14}]\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}\,\frac{1}{1-z^3}\color{blue}{=45}
  \end{align*}

**Condition $x_1\neq x_2$:**

- We respect this condition by subtracting from (1) all solutions with $x_1=x_2$. This gives
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{2x_2+x_3+x_4=19}\tag{3}
  \end{align*}
  The number of positive solutions of (3) is
  \begin{align*}
  [z^{19}]\frac{z^2}{1-z^2}\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^2=[z^{15}]\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}\,\frac{1}{1-z^2}\color{blue}{=72}
  \end{align*}

**Conditions $x_2\ne 2x_3$ and $x_1\neq x_2$:**

- In (2) and (3) we did some overcounting, since we counted $x_2=2x_3$ *and* $x_1= x_2$  twice. We have to compensate this by subtracting once the number of solutions of (1) with $x_1=x_2=2x_3$, which gives
  \begin{align*}
   \color{blue}{5x_3+x_4=19}\tag{4}
   \end{align*}
  The number of positive solutions of (4) is
  \begin{align*}
  [z^{19}]\frac{z^5}{1-z^5}\,\frac{z}{1-z}=[z^{14}]\frac{1}{1-z^5}\,\frac{1}{1-z}\color{blue}{=3}
  \end{align*}

Combining (1) to (4) we find the number of wanted solutions is
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{816-45-72+3=702}
\end{align*}

Comment: @RobPratt: Yes, many thanks. Mistake corrected.

Comment: Why isn't this answer accepted yet$?$ thanks @epi163sqrt as I was also looking for an answer for these type of questions

Comment: @Vanessa: You're welcome. :-)